# Can I prevent the particular default event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have to prevent default tap event from the page.
If I use `event.preventDefault()`,it prevents all events.

Can I prevent particular default event?

Comment: `If I use event.preventDefault() it prevents all events` No - it prevents the event you're listening for. It would help a lot to see your code here, along with a clearer description of what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

it's as simple as this.

just change "click" to "tap"

i used "click" for example purposes only

let me know if it helps

```js
$("a").on("click",function(event){
   event.preventDefault();
});
```

```css
a {
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  background:red;
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="www.stackoverflow.com"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
if (event.type === 'click') {
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

Just change to check for the desired event type.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this,

```
function preventSpecificEvent(event) {
     if (event.keyCode == 9){
         event.preventDefault();
     }
    //Here 9 is the keycode for tab, 
    //YOu can find keycode of any key from 
    //https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/javascript-keycodes/
}
```

Thanks